# What is causing the first block of code to work but the second to return a syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm practicing Python with problems on a website and the my program is returning a Syntax error on Line 9, yet on the example answer to the problem provided on the website, the same line of code is that is in my program is working without error. Just curious as to what is causing the problem in my program? The point of the problem is to take numbers from 2 lists, find the even numbers from list one and finding the odd from list 2 and creating a 3rd list using the even and odds. I changed it up to find the even and odd from both and make both an even and an odd list pulling from both list one and two but I was thinking it should still work...

Pretty new to Python. Not quite sure what to even try.

## Provided code from Website:

```
def mergeList(listOne, listTwo):
  thirdList = []
  for num in listOne:
    if(num % 2 != 0):
      thirdList.append(num)
  for num in listTwo:
    if(num % 2 == 0):
      thirdList.append(num)
  return thirdList

print("Merged List is")
listOne = [10, 20, 23, 11, 17]
listTwo = [13, 43, 24, 36, 12]
print(mergeList(listOne, listTwo))
```

## My code

```
list1 = [81, 71, 61, 34, 55]
list2 = [14, 19, 48, 32, 91]

def mergelist(list1, list2):
    mergedlist = list1 + list2
    even = []
    odd = []
    for num in mergedlist:
        if (num % 2 = 0):
            even.append(num)
            else:
            odd.append(num)
print("even: " + even)
print("odd: " + odd)
```

My program should merge list 1 and 2 into one list, "mergedlist", and then search the list for even numbers and appending them to the even list. The non even numbers, odds, should be appended to the odd list. Then finally print both the even and odd lists. My program is saying that there is a syntax error on line 9.

Comment: your else should begin where if is. So you need to delete the tab/space before else. also use == instead of =

Answer (score 1):

You have one equals sign, which is assignment, and can't be done in an if statement.

You need two equals signs, as the original had. And you don't need parens:

```
if num % 2 == 0:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [81, 71, 61, 34, 55]   
list2 = [14, 19, 48, 32, 91] 

def mergelist(list1, list2):
  mergedlist = list1 + list2
  even = []
  odd = []
  for num in mergedlist:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        even.append(num)
    else:
        odd.append(num)
  print("even:", even)
  print("odd:", odd)
```

## calling the function

```
mergelist(list1, list2)
```

Above code is working version of your code with following corrections
1) As said in previous answer you need relational/comparison operator "==" in place of assignment operator "=" with if condition.
2) Indentation for else and following statement was wrong.
3) list can't be concatenated so you should use , in place of +
4) Finally you must call the function with arguments outside .

Comment: When providing working code, you should also explain why it works when the poster's code doesn't.

Comment: @JoshKarpel : It seems your suggestion has been taken care of in the edited answer. In that case, you should perhaps revert the downvote, if you have downvoted.